# How can I copy .out files to the new folder from a folder including 120 subfolders which also including 120 subfolders? (by using Python, Bash or R )

Tags: python, bash

I have tried to use os.walk(), however, I could not figure out how could I take files from the subfolders of the subfolders.

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
import pathlib
import shutil

data_dir = 'your/path'
output_dir = 'output/dir'

for filename in pathlib.Path(data_dir).glob('**/*.out'):
    shutil.move(filename, output_dir)
```

**Bash**: `find your/path -iname '*.out' | xargs -i{} mv {} output/dir`